# Move me to form. What am I?

Tags: riddle

> I will form with your movements.
>
> Every movement may not be correct.
>
> Wrong movement will make me noisy.
>
> Everyone can make mistake by guessing me.
>
> I am visible.

**What am I?**

Comment: who or what...?

Comment: I voted to close as too broad. Three lines seem definitely not enough to constitute a riddle.

Comment: Agreed with @IAmInPLS: this seems too short to have a unique answer. If you edit it to add more lines so that only one answer can possibly fit the riddle, I'll retract my vote to close :-)

Comment: Ok i will edit it now

Comment: @SathiReddy I edited my answers, still fit. Maybe you can say if there are ok or not

Comment: Damn, the last one completely nullifies my answer.

Answer (score 6):

Are you

> A song (played on an instrument like piano)

```
I will form with your movements.
```

> A song, build by the movements of your finger

```
Every movement may not be correct.
```

> Wrong finger on a piano touch may not be correct in the song.

```
Wrong movement will make me noisy.
```

> If you do a false note on a piano, everyone will hear it, because it's too noisy and doesn't fit

```
Everyone can make mistake by guessing me.
```

> Many song, hard to recognize the right one. (If you have friends who start guitar, you know what I'm talking about)

```
I'm visible
```

> Writted on a paper

Comment: I was about to write this.. just a change suggestion : music can be made out of anything if rightly played or struck. Rest is just noise

Comment: I thought the same but he is asking who not what.

Comment: @nikamed "Who" is often used metaphorically in riddles, even if the solution isn't a person. Similarly, the first person pronoun is often used ("I" usually refers only to people) even though the solution is an object. Anyway the OP has now edited the question to say "what" and not "who".

Comment: @Guildias .. well tried.. But my answer is different from that. But i upvoted you.

Answer (score 3):

Another try, more funny :

Are you

> A balloon being filled

```
I will form with your movements.
```

> With your blow

```
Every movement may not be correct.
```

> Try to filled with your nose, you will see.

```
Wrong movement will make me noisy.
```

> If you don't close your mouth, if you try to blow will making a hole in it. Or to filled to much and make it pop.

```
Everyone can make mistake by guessing me.
```

> Can be taken for a gun shot if too much filled and explosed. Or for some other things everybody does, but, no one want to be heard doing it.

```
I'm visible
```

> Visible as a balloon.

Just to say there's many possibilities. Maybe a specification is needed

Answer (score 2):

Are you

> Conscience?

I will form with your movements.

> Conscience is usually formed with experience or doing things.

Every movement may not be correct.

> You can do wrong actions.

Wrong movement will make me noisy.

> In other words, guilt. Guilt is usually recurring and annoying which is like noise.

Everyone can make mistake by guessing me.

> When using conscience, you would need to think thoroughly. If you guess you could make mistakes.

Comment: maybe is too broad but this answer i dont think it fits :/

Comment: oh well, at least I tried

Comment: yeah! who knows, maybe karma will slap my face and proves this is the right answer lol

Answer (score 1):

Are you

> Lego bricks

I will form with your movements.

> without your movement ,it will not make a structure

Every movement may not be correct.

> How much master you are....but all of your moves may not be correct

Wrong movement will make me noisy.

> Lego brick structure will fall if you make a wrong choice.

Everyone can make mistake by guessing me.

> if structure is not complete,then each one make a guess

I am visible.

> sure it is

Comment: Unexpected answer ^^

Comment: was actually thinking of this, but thought it was too much of a stretch

Answer (score 0):

Are you

> Writing?

I will form with your movements

> Your movements determine what you write.

Every movement may not be correct

> You can misspell words

Wrong movement will make me noisy

> Misspelled words can make text look bad or hard to read.

Everyone can make mistake by guessing me

> Guessing how to spell can lead to mistakes? Also I think this is also in line with the grammatical error (I believe its supposed to be mistakes?)

I am visible

> Writing or text is indeed visible

Move me to form

> You can move a pen to form words.

Answer (score 0):

Are you

> Chalk

```
I will form with your movements / Move me to form
```

> You write with chalk by moving it about in specific ways.

```
Every movement may not be correct
```

> You can misspell words, or use chalk incorrectly (see next point).

```
Wrong movement will make me noisy
```

> The jittering and screeching noise that can be heard when using chalk incorrectly.

```
Everyone can make mistake by guessing me
```

> The first time someone endeavours to write word 'chalk', they may misspell it (e.g. 'chock')?
>  One may make mistakes while writing (and hence the common blackboard eraser)?
>  Chalk powder may be mistaken for some other substance?

```
I am visible
```

> The piece of chalk itself, as well as what it has written, is visible.